# Environment variable in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

We are trying to use `${server.config.dir}` in jvmOptions

```
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=${server.config.dir}/kerberos/client_jaas.conf
```

Can we set this as part of Jenkins environment variables?

We did it like this-

```
environment {
        server.config.dir="some directory"
}
```

and we are getting this error-

```
WorkflowScript: 37: Expected string literal @ line 37, column 9.
           server.conf.dir="serverconfigdir"
           ^
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates a string literal is expected, and the special characters are causing the compiler to not read the key in the `environment` directive as a string literal. You need to explicitly cast it as a literal string:

```
environment {
  'server.config.dir' = "some directory"
}
```

and the error will be fixed.